# How to send file from React to Webform via Rest

Tags: webforms

I want to send an attached file in a React form to Drupal Webform via REST , but don't know how.
I am sending the other fields successffully. They appear in the List with submissions. Here is my code:

```
//get token
fetch('https://my-site.com/session/token', {
    method: "GET"
})
.then(response => {
    if (200 === response.status) {
        // send submission
        fetch('https://my-site.com/webform_rest/submit?_format=json', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-Token': response
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'webform_id': 'form_id',
                'entity_type': null,
                'entity_id': null,
                'in_draft': false,
                'uri': ['/webform/form_id/api'],
                'email': email,
                'phone': phone,
                'name': name,
            }),
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (data) => {
                console.log('success', data)
                setMessage('The message was sent!')
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('error', error)
                setMessage('Network error! The message was not sent!')
            }
        )
    }else{
        // error: didn't manage to get the token
        setMessage('Network error!')
    }
})
```

Please someone to explain the necessary steps or to provide an example.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are using the Webform REST module this is not yet a feature https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rest/issues/2899902.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is about the REST/JSON:API in Drupal generally, and not specifically about Webform REST.

To attach a file via REST/JSON:API, you need two requests:

1. The request to add the file
2. The request to add your entity (the webform/node, etc. that you want to attach the file to)

For REST, see this [change record for an example of how to upload a file](https://www.drupal.org/node/2941420).

For JSON:API, see this [change record for an example](https://www.drupal.org/node/3024331).

[Work is underway in Core to unify how REST and JSON:API handle file uploads](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2940383); the issue is postponed but only because it has been broken up into sub-issues.